# add buttons to footer in UIView in which footer is fixed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, xcode6

I have a UIView with UIScroll for it. I want to add buttons for footer in which the footer is fixed and the scroll continues… Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what do you want to do with those buttons?

Comment: i want to add buttons to the footer inorder to move to next view when i press on those buttons

Comment: why don't you try Tab bar Controller for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like.

Place your scrollview on view and leave some space from bottom for button. then add button on that space. set contraint to it. its simple.

Answer (score 2):

See the view hierarchy in attached screenshot :

You can bind the button action and scroll as per your requirenment.

[image]

Full heirarchy :

[image]

Comment: @venu Is it helpful to you?

Comment: Accept my answer if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Take one UIView like containerview. 
Add scrollview and button in that view

Answer (score 0):

You need to subview a view on scrolls views super view. Set the constraints to the bottom. Then add button on top of the newly added view.

Keep your scroll view behind your newly added view. SO that it will scroll and not the bottom newly added view.